# jquery .remove not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following which is supposed to remove the element ".mycontainer" when I click on a close button. It's not removing the element though. When I use firebug. I can see that it is just moving it to outside of the html tags at the beginning on the code.

```
    $('.closeButton').click( function() {
       $(".mycontainer").slideUp( function() {
           $(".closeButton").parent().appendTo(".ContentsHolder");        
           $(this).remove();
       });
    });
```

It works if I comment out the 3rd line `//$(".closeButton").parent().appendTo(".ContentsHolder");`

but this removes the content so I can't access it again.

EDIT:

My html looks something like this if it helps to understand what I'm doing...

```
<div class='ContentsHolder'>

</div>
<div class='mycontainer'>
    <div class='myContent'>
        <a class='closebutton'>close</a>
        ... other content ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also managed to make it work by putting a delay on the removal of mycontainer `$(this).delay(500).remove();`

I would not think this is a great solution though.

Comment: Can you show us some html as well :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved same problem before like this:

```
$(".mycontainer").slideUp(500, function() { 
    $(this).remove(); 
});
```

Comment: this does work... it's the extra line that I have in my example that causes it to break...

Comment: Could it rather be, that missing delay is what is causing the problems here.

Answer (score 2):

You could just chain the remove function after the slideUp like so :

```
 $('.closeButton').click( function() {
       $(".mycontainer").slideUp( function() {
           $(".closeButton").parent().appendTo(".ContentsHolder");        
       }).remove();
    });
```

Comment: this removes the parent of closebutton before it has been appended to ContentsHolder

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `$(this)` is a different context to what you think.

Try adding `console.log($(this));` to see the actual context in the console.

```
$('.closeButton').click( function() {
    $(".mycontainer").slideUp( function() {
        $(".closeButton").parent().appendTo(".ContentsHolder");
        console.log($(this));
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```